# How to use result of first api, into second api call in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I want to use the result of first api, into second api call. Scenario is like that, I want to use the result of first api, into second api call. If I am correct then I want synchronous api call(not sure). I tried to write following function but not working. function2 is call before function1. **In function2 we are use result1 which is only come when function1 is called before function2**, How I do.

```
$scope.function1 = function(){
        var deferred= $q.defer();    
        $http.post(api1, data1)
        .success(function(response, status) {
          if (response.error == 0) {
            console.log(response.result);          
               $scope.result1=response.result;      
          }           
        }) ;    
        deferred.resolve('Success') ; 
        return deferred.promise;       
    };
    var promise =  $scope.addDefaultValue();
    promise.then(function(){
      $scope.function2();
    });

     $scope.function2=function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(api2,result1)
        .success(function(response, status){
          if(response.error == 0){

          }
        });
      deferred.resolve('Success') ;
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: What is problem with approach suggested by Julian.  http call inside http..

Comment: @Julian why you delete you answer, my code is working with your approach.....

Comment: maybe because your approach is "bad"? It's like if someone asks how to shut her computer down, she tried calling the electric company with no avail. Then one of the answers advices to cancel her contract with the electric company, just to shut her computer down. the answer would be correct, because it works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert `$http` requests to "synchronous". That's not what "deferred" does. Deferred is a way to convert non-promise-capable functions to promise-capable functions. `$http` functions return promise objects so you don't need to use deferred.

```
$http.post(api, data1).then(function (response) {
  $scope.result1 = response.data.result;
  // return is important here
  // so that you can keep chaining with .then
  return $http.post(api2, response.data.result);
}).then(function (response) {
  // here you have response from api2
  $scope.result2 = response.data.result;
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  // here you can handle errors
  // from either api calls
  // second api call won't be made if the first one fails
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: `response` is a promise object . Should be accessing `response.data`

Comment: @mostruash What is problem with approach suggested by Julian. http call inside http

Comment: I guess Julian deleted his answer so I don't know.

Comment: @geeks Julian answer wasn't really wrong although `success` is deprecated in favor of using `then`

Answer (score 1):

You could follow promise chain pattern here, follow chaining using `.then` on promise object.

No need to create extra overhead promise using `$q`, as `$http` methods returns promise object when they start an ajax.

**Code**

```
$scope.function1 = function() {
  return $http.post(api1, data1)
    .then(function(d) {
    var response = d.data;
    if (response.error == 0) {
      console.log(response.result);
      $scope.result1 = response.result;
    }
    return response;
  });
};

$scope.function1().then(function(data) {
  $scope.function2();
}, function(error) {

});
```